# How do you pick your norm for a Linear Functional on a real Banach Space?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations

How do you know which "formula" to pick for your norm on a real Banach Space?

A question I found in my book asks to compute the norm for a certain linear functional on a real Banach Space $C[0,1]\mapsto \mathbb{R}$, (so the real Banach space is the Vector Space in question). The linear functional maps to a scalar, (as per definition), but what does it mean to "compute its norm"? Which of the many formulas should I pick?

Any insight on this problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ is a normed vector space with norm $\| \cdot\|_V$ and $f: V \to W$ is a linear map to a normed vector space $W$ with norm $\|\cdot \|_W$, (In your case $V$ is Banach and $W = \mathbb{R}$), then we define the norm of $f$ by $\|f\| = \sup \{\|f(v) \|_W \mid \|v\|_V = 1\}.$ There are many equivalent formulations, but the whole point is that they are equivalent.